# Cocos2d V2.X signal SIGABRT when I Create and run first time

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Hello I am trying to follow a guide from `raywenderlich` which is Beat em up game For cocos2d V2.x But when I create and run the project it gives an error signal SIGABRT.

[image]

[image]

I am very new to cocos2d and objective c. Wanted to start with cocos2d-x C++ but couldnt find a good guide for beat up game. I want to make rpg games and this was the closest one. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the same version of Xcode and Cocos2D as the tutorial?

The easiest thing to do, is to download the completed tutorial at the bottom of the page and try to run it either in your compiler or on your device.

This will tell you if its a compatibility issue or your code.